# Can Linq project an List of int to another list of class T

Tags: linq

I have a list of int and I wonder if I can create another list of object T based on the previous list using Linq.

To simplify the issue:

I have a list of int like that: 1,2,3,4
and I expect to have (1,2), (2,4), (3,6), (4,8)

Normally, we can do that easily without Linq

```
public class T
    {
        int first;
        int Second;
        public T(int x, int y)
        {
            first = x;
            Second = y;
        }
    }


class Program
    {
         static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int> series = new List<int>() { 1,2,3,4 };
            List<T> obj = new List<T>();
            foreach (int item in series)
            {
               obj.Add(new T(item,item*2));
            }
        }
    }
```

That worked perfectly.
But when I tried to use Linq

```
List<T> obj = series.Select(x=> {new T(x,x*2)}).ToList<T>();
```

I thought it would work but I got an error saying

```
Error   2   The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.Select<TSource,TResult>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,int,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.
```

What have I done incorrectly? I am still a newbie (of probably a few month old) learning Linq  :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Get rid of the curly braces...

```
List<T> obj = series.Select(x=> new T(x,x*2)).ToList<T>();
```

When you write a lambda like:

```
x => x * 2
```

It's assumed that the right side is the return value. When you use curly braces, it's expecting you to actually use the return keyword, like this:

```
x => { return x * 2; }
```

When you don't, I bet it's assuming the lambda returns `void`.

Comment: I got it John. Many thanks! So according to what you explained, this one is also ok and equivalent: List<T> obj = series.Select(x => { return new T(x, x * 2); }).ToList<T>();

Comment: Exactly. Typically people use the shorter format unless they need more than one line of code.

Comment: agreed! My question was just to validate my understanding of what you explained. Shorter is always better as far as coding is concerned.